# What should we do with anonymous user feedback?

Tags: discussion, anonymous, post-feedback

I deployed some basic reporting on the [anon and low rep post feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing):

https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback (10k users only)

Turns out this system is **really** effective at getting feedback about the long tail.

On average feedback is left on posts that are **6 months** older than the posts being voted on.

The reporting has highlighted areas where there is information rot, for example these questions contain old unhelpful content that people stopped voting on:

- [When should I use a struct instead of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class)
- [Response.Redirect to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104601/asp-net-response-redirect-to-new-window)
- [What is the basic difference between the Factory and Abstract Factory Patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001767/design-patterns-factory-vs-abstract-factory/4913001#4913001)
- [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-usi)
- [How can I reverse the ON bits in a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750/reverse-on-bits-in-a-byte)
- [CSS background color in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319/css-background-color-in-javascript)

Here are some questions containing apparently helpful information, that people stopped voting on:

- [What is a privileged instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89607)
- [How to temporarily disable a message listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625725/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-message-listener)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970121/are-these-good-interview-questions-for-flex-developer
- [Is a JOIN faster than a WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129923/is-a-join-faster-than-a-where)
- [How to group by week in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736010/how-to-group-by-week-in-mysql)

Looking through these question lists it is pretty clear that we need a strategy to deal with **high value** content that has been either "abandoned" or "neglected".

Over a question's lifetime it attracts many answers and the answers attract many comments. This makes it way harder for an end user to decipher what the solution to the problem is.

---

Now that we have some pretty good ways to isolate **high value** questions, what can we do to shape them up?

Do we need new site features to deal directly with this problem? (EG. edit bounty/edit voting)

Comment: I wonder whether a common source of 'No's in the feedback might be posts that don't answer users' particular questions.  These would arise when a title catches the eye in a search result, but the post doesn't contain what the user is looking for.

Maybe I'm misinterpreting, but anonymous feedback has a much higher proportion of 'downs' than registered feedback, which might be because anonymous feedback is drive-by and indicative of 'failed' search click-thrus.

Comment: @waffles, I've think you've run into the 'posting at non-optimal time of the day' problem with this one.  I expected a lot more activity.

Comment: @Martin --  "Did this answer help you?"  "No.  It's a really good answer, but as it happened, it didn't help with my particular problem."  Maybe we shouldn't read too much into those stats.

Comment: @Waffles: From your examples, it's not clear to me what you mean by helpful and unhelpful content no longer being voted on, or high value content that has been abandoned or neglected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this discussion as **obsolete** because this feature was [abandoned by Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209787/263422).

Comment: @Cœur: It isn't really obsolete, since it's still perfectly possible to visit /tools/post-feedback on any site in which you have the relevant privilege and see the current stats. (I just checked on Space Exploration.) The team can apply [status-walking-dead] if they want, but there's no real reason to close.

Comment: @NathanTuggy then explain why other feature requests get closed as off-topic? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122699/provide-a-questions-only-filter-for-the-post-feedback-tool

Comment: @Cœur: I just voted to reopen that anyway, so my explanation would be "folks had higher expectations of the imminent death of the feature back then." (It was closed, what, a few weeks after Nick's post?) Clearly those expectations did not pan out.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, OK, thanks, then I'm retracting my close-flag here. :)

Answer (score 32):

**Short Answer:**

I suggest creating another tab, **[archive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/archive)**, with the following subtabs for organizing questions.

- **Active Feedback**: For questions with several feedback responses (say 25 or more?)
- **Dormant**: Questions ordered by number of days without **any** activity.
- **Feedback Issue**: Questions where (#No - #Yes) > (#Upvotes - #Downvotes) *as this may indicate information rot*.

And perhaps others?

I would then add a privilege allowing users with 1000 reputation ?or more? to view counts #Yes / #No next to vote counts (but only if they click to view vote counts).

I would then add two badges:

- http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Archaeologist&c=s 100 edits to questions after six months of inactivity.  (IOW: date of edit - date of previous edit or question post >= six months)
- http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Preservationist&c=s (perhaps bronze or gold?) 100 edits to questions flagged as *Feedback Issue* -- see above.

**Statistical Background:** You have a binary response (Yes/No).  I think you basically want to know: *Why did the user click Yes or No?*  Then, based on **why**, should the community / moderators / helpful low rep users take some action.  Quoting directly:

> Now that we have some pretty good ways to isolate **high value** questions, what can we do to shape them up?

*In other words, what are the appropriate actions?*  As for actions, we have:

- Close/Delete question
- Edit Question/Answers
- Do nothing

I believe the answer of 'Why did the user click Y/N?' will fall into one of a few categories.  But think first for a minute what we know about this person.  *Pretty much nothing*.  If they're anonymous, *why didn't they sign up*?  Is there some barrier preventing them from signing up? If they're a low rep user, why haven't they gained **15 rep** to upvote?  [Zoe probably has 15 rep just from standing on the keyboard](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/workin-on-ur-problemz/).

With significant User Feedback: **Yes**

- Perhaps feature this question in the ads to the right? (server-side)

With significant User Feedback: **No** [Note this insight from Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing/98820#98820)

- When question has several downvotes, perhaps it should be closed?
- When question has several upvotes, perhaps it should be edited for clarity or information rot.
- When question has no upvoted answers, close/delete it? (This was Jeff's suggestion in a [comment below the insight from Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing/98820#98820)

With all that said, I doubt you'll be able to predict **why** a user responded the way they did **without** collecting more information from them (via cookies or something).  ie. What (if anything) did they just search for??

Hence, I suggest the archive tab instead of trying to determine *why* a user responded Yes/No.

Comment: I love the badge suggestion

Comment: I really like this. I'd suggest "conservationist" rather than "preservationist", though, because if you're editing a question, one thing you're not doing is preserving it...

Comment: When I came up with the name "preservationist", I had [googled](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=preservationist+vs+conservationist), and apparently this distinction is known. **I'm open to either one.**  I just thought of *preserving it from deletion...* as opposed to *conserving space & deleting it...*

Comment: Regarding your suggestion on information rot, a mere difference might not be helpful, as the number of anonymous users will always be greater than the number of voters... perhaps a normalized approach would help. Otherwise, good ideas.

Comment: Sure thing, Suggestion excellent yoda. Speak wise you do.

Comment: Archaeologist and Excavator badges are in the oven

Comment: Isn't this post `status-completed` ?? I see the badges: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/158/excavator http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/157/archaeologist

Answer (score 13):

Here are my suggestions:

**`Suggestion #1:`**

Badges can be awarded to answer with **n** anonymous votes = (anonymous useful votes -  anonymous not useful votes). The badges can be awarded multiple times. The actual count be determined by moderators based on the data that they have gathered so far. I am not sure if 10,000 is too less for Gold badge.

1. **[Omniscient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/omniscient)**: One having total knowledge. Gold badge. Total useful + not useful votes greater than or equal to 10,000.
2. **[Profound](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/profound)**: (adj.) showing or requiring great knowledge or understanding. Silver badge. Total useful + not useful votes greater than or equal to 5,000.
3. **[Cognizant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cognizant)**: (adj.) aware; having knowledge. Bronze badge. Total useful + not useful votes greater than or equal to 1,000.

[image]

---

**`Suggestion #2:`**

1. Add a new section just above comments section that displays the count of useful and not useful votes by anonymous users.

[image: Separate section to show anonymous votes]

---

**`Suggestion #3:`**

1. When the first anonymous user clicks the *Yes* button, a comment with the message `Yes, this post was useful.` can be posted under user *Community* with an upvote and subsequent clicks by anonymous users can be added as upvotes.
2. When the first anonymous user clicks the *No* button, a comment with the message `No, this post was not useful.` can be posted under user *Community* with an upvote and subsequent clicks by anonymous users can be added as upvotes. Even though, actually speaking it is not an upvote for the answer but it is a support to that comment saying that the answer is not helpful.

[image: Posting the anonymous users' votes as comments with an upvote to the comment.]

Comment: Logically - 3 people agree that "this post was not helpful", so it should be **+3** anyway. Either way, I don't think it should be displayed as comment - it isn't a comment.

Comment: I took the liberty of undeleting this and upvoting it because it is something we have considered-- not sure we will go this route, but it does capture the *intent* which is to give anon users a constrained voice ala prefab comments

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - Someone commented that you don't like having too many comments in the posts. I thought it doesn't add any value to have a suggestion pointing towards that direction. That's why I deleted it. Anyway, thanks for undeleting and upvoting the post.

Comment: Hrm, I think that was me who left the comment... I didn't intend for you to take it as any type of official position, I was merely theorizing. Don't let people prod you into deleting suggestions that you think are good.

Comment: I like this idea, but seeing the Up/Down votes against the Helpful/Unhelpful looks really strange...I figured the upvote count to a lot of users meant "this is really helpful"

Comment: Agree, but only the +1 votes should count. If something wasn't helpful, it's not a good answer anyway.

Comment: These numbers are really off. About 50 posts would be eligible for the bronze badge. Only one would get the silver. None have yet to reach the gold.

Answer (score 8):

Grab bag of suggestions:

- If we could filter the post-feedback lists by tag we could focus more efficiently on our areas of expertise.
- Where multiple answers to a question have feedback, these could be grouped and associated with the question, or perhaps the 'highest ranked' of those answers.  Then all the feedback for the answers to one question would appear together.

Answer (score 5):

I have a few ideas, some of which are bold:

1. **Add questions / answers to [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/).**  It seems to me that these questions an answers are easily cleaned up when brought to the attention of the community.  I suggest that questions / answers which have a high value (such as through an Anonymous User feedback algorithm) should be highlighted through the existing **review** section.  This could be, for example, a new tab next to **first answers**.
2. **Add bounties to good questions without good answers.**  Administrators (or [the community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)) could put out a bounty for good and high value questions which do not have good (or currently appropriate) answers.  If such a question already has an accepted answer that is no longer good, the voting process should rise the cream, and perhaps the bounty could be manually awarded.  (Perhaps this concept is slightly different than a bounty is currently.)
3. **Automatically protect old good questions with good answers.**  The system could automatically protect good and high-value questions with good and high-value answers.  This would prevent noise (such as low value comments and answers) that make an otherwise good question and its answer appear dusty and useless.
4. **Automatically delete old, useless comments.**  The system could automatically delete comments older than X months with fewer than Y upvotes.  Good comments will stay, but not-so-useful comments will be left behind.

Comment: +1 I really like the idea of auto-protecting old, good questions.

Comment: Hmm, it seems you're saying that comments without upvotes aren't good comments. With this I wouldn't agree.

Comment: Of all of them, #4 is certainly the one I'm least sure is a good idea.  I agree that not all comments without upvotes are bad comments.  But I do think that the vast majority of unhelpful / bad / obsolete comments comments have 0 upvotes.

Comment: There are also a bunch of comments with tons of upvotes that are fairly useless as well. [Insert favorite comment rant here]...

Comment: Deleting comments might break the chain of discussion, to the point where the high-voted comments become gibberish robbed of their context. Bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

I took a look at the first question (struct/class) and see that a fair of the content is ok.  The hugely upvoted accepted answer's link still functions, and it's not really a concept that goes out of date.  I think the comments on the accepted answer, are relevant to the answer.

There is a problem with a few of the answers in that they are treating it like a forum, so they're just points being made, that would better be comments.  Most of the answers are ok for such a beginner question.

Looking at a few more questions down the list, I see some good questions with a host of what seem to be good answers (without having full technical understanding if they are or not).  There's a few bad answers in there, and a few old comments, but I'm not seeing it being a big issue.

Comment: I don't have time to look at them all today, have to run, so I'll see what things look like tomorrow.

Comment: it has **13** answers many of which are of little to no value ... a pile of comments that make no sense and so on ... its classic info rot problem

Comment: @waffles, ok, by `info rot` I thought you meant that all the information was no longer relevant.  I guess you mean that there is some useless info and some useless Meta info.

Comment: @waffles, looking closer, I see that there most of the answers are ok for a beginner question like that, but there are some that are basically treating it like a forum.  answer edited.

Comment: @waffles, I looked at a few more, and just saw good questions with a lot of good answers (without having the technical knowledge to evaluate all of them), and maybe a bad answer or two.  I'm not really sure there's an issue here.

Comment: @waffles, I like Siva's suggestion for a starting point, just keep it as a simple comment so no extra UI added (just a little code under the hood).

Answer (score 3):

Community should adjust the random bumping of old questions to take feedback in account. Questions with unhelpful but upvoted answers should be bumped more often than the others, so that they can get more eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if old questions that are no longer allowed by the various policies that have been put into place are really useless. You might be surprised...