# What is the point of 'was this post useful'?

Tags: support, post-feedback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)

What is the point of the 'was this post useful' question under every answer?

I thought that was voting's job.

[image]

Comment: *"I thought that was voting's job."* Yes, except that anonymous users can't vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It only shows up if you're not logged in: it's to allow anonymous users a means to provide some amount of feedback that they can't otherwise do without reputation.

More info:

[Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)