# Who gets the "Was this post useful to you?" feedback?

Tags: support, post-feedback

I just read [this Electronics SE answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28081). I found the explanation very clear and interesting, but I don't want to create an account on that site. So, I clicked **Yes** by "Was this post useful to you?"

Who will get that feedback?

Comment: If Sathya gets his way, [moderators and 10k+ users will](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116715/give-moderators-10k-users-a-way-to-view-the-anonymous-feedback-data-for-a-specif). EDIT: Er, I mean, [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99370/what-should-we-do-with-anonymous-user-feedback).

Comment: Also related: [What is the point of 'was this post useful'?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101201/what-is-the-point-of-was-this-post-useful), [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some statistics are available to 10k users in the tools section, via https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback

These pages shows some general statistics on the feedback (like feedback/score correlation), and there are tabs that list the most over/under-rated posts, as well as the most and least helpful posts.

Moderators probably have finer-grained information, and obviously Stack Exchange staff more so.

See also:
[What should we do with anonymous user feedback?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99370/what-should-we-do-with-anonymous-user-feedback)

Looks like this on Stack Overflow:

[image]

Answer (score 22):

The 10k tools page is dead for some time now (over a year) however the team added the PostFeedback table to the public data dump, accessible for example via [data explorer](//data.stackexchange.com/).

[Quick count](//data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266885/total-amount-of-anonymous-feedback-clicks) of rows showing over 23 millions records at this time. (September 2016)

At some point a field IsAnonymous was added as well, to let us know when the vote was cast by a logged in user with less than 15 reputation. At this time (September 2016) there are about 800,000 such recorded votes.

Another interesting query is [Anonymous feedback votes over time](//data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266887/anonymous-feedback-votes-over-time), showing steady increase in votes:

[image]

(last month doesn't really count as it's not yet finished)

Answer (score 14):

The feedback is recorded in a page that is visible to 10k users and moderators on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback, in the case of the site you are referring.

The page reports some statistics about the anonymous feedback, and makes a comparison between anonymous feedback, and the votes given to the same posts.

This is how the top of that page appears on *English Language & Usage*.

[image: screenshot]

The same information is visible to moderators, who don't get more data. This is what I see on *Drupal Answers*, where I am a moderator.

[image: screenshot]

Even the rest of the page is not different, if I compare what I see in a site where I am a 20K user with what I see on *Drupal Answers*, I don't see any difference.