# What are participation rates for Stack Overflows "was this post useful to you" button?

Tags: support, users, feedback, research, community-data

I just asked [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33124/how-frequent-is-user-feedback-on-an-onsite-poll) question on stackexchange (webmasters) and @danlefree suggested that I try asking meta if it was possible to access some general statistics (even partial) about how high a % of anonymous users gave feedback on the stack exchange using this data gathering tool which displays for unregistered and low rep users:

[image]

Apparently users who have over 10k rep can see [some statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125779/who-gets-the-was-this-post-useful-to-you-feedback) in the tools section, though not only is this unaccessible to me, I would prefer a greater overview of data.

How can I find out the % of anonymous users who click either "Yes" or "No" on this feedback tool?

Comment: If you're familiar with SQL, you can find some of this information (though it is not real-time) in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).  Specifically, the "PostFeedback" table.  Here is an example query: [Feedback on my posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts)

Comment: Interesting, the participation rate on my questions for feedback is *much* lower than I would have thought; there's only a very small amount of votes relative to actual rep votes.  But maybe that's because the feedback system is relatively new, and most of my posts are relatively old (six months or more).