# What is the purpose of table PostFeedback in Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer, post-feedback

The title says it all. What is the data that is contained in the PostFeedback table. I can see that there are columns `isAnonymous`(either true or false) and `VoteTypeId`(either upvote or downvote). But aren't the votes present in `Votes` table? Then, what are the votes in `PostFeedback` table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the purpose:

> [image]

And in words: when anonymous visitor (and probably unregistered user as well) is browsing a question, he can click the upvote arrow and it sends a "feedback", which is then being stored in that table you asked about.

This information has no actual effect (no reputation, no badges, no public access) however it's used to collect statistics that are available to 10K users via [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback).

More information is available here: [Who gets the "Was this post useful to you?" feedback?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125779/152859)

Comment: So, if isAnonymous is true, that means the voter is unregistered. If it is false, he is registered but doesn't have privileges to vote. Right?

Comment: @Ramblin'Man nope, the other way around as far as I know. Unregistered means actual user, anonymous means random visitor who never posted an answer.