# Public upvote counter

Tags: feature-request, voting, post-feedback

How about a 'public' upvote counter, just above the normal upvote one.

This counter is to count is for public people so anyone who doesn't have SE account can upvote an answer he had a use of it.

Maybe make it replace the normal upvote counter when a guest is surfing, and when logged in, normal upvote takes place again

**EDIT:** I think SE can use **Local Storage** to store some id or something so the answer doesn't get re-publicly-upvoted due to dynamic IP change

Comment: There is already a mechanism to track anonymous feedback: [Who gets the "Was this post useful to you?" feedback?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125779)

Comment: Above that, we sometimes have problems getting users to vote correctly, how are we supposed to rely on all of the visitors' votes?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not >10k reputation user, not guests are, I mean, even a guest when he comes and sees a lot of upvotes he would ge encouraged to try the answer or whatever

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Then that's why it's a separate counter

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Also,what kind of problems?

Comment: Why do we need that seperate counter? What benefits does it have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't given any reason as to how this would work, why you suggest it, or why this would be useful/beneficial.

> This counter is to count is for public people so anyone who doesn't
>   have SE account can upvote an answer he had a use of it.

And what happens to the vote from the user not logged in?
Does it get added to the current vote count, just like votes from users who are logged in?
Or are you suggesting a new additional vote count for "votes by non-logged in users"?

> EDIT: I think SE can use Local Storage to store some id or something
>   so the answer doesn't get re-publicly-upvoted due to dynamic IP change

You are getting ahead of yourself a little bit.
You're trying to solve technical problems when you haven't even explained what this is all for.

Such potential problems can be ironed out by Stack devs, what you need to do at the moment is explain your request/proposal/ideas so we know *what* exactly you are proposing and *why*, and how it would work etc.

Currently, you idea is to "allow non-logged users a special vote button", but what does it do, and why does it do it?

Answer (score 0):

> How about a 'public' upvote counter

This is clearly open to abuse. Immature users who want to boost their profile or take part in childish 'I'm better than you' competitiveness could and probably would sit there all day voting for their own questions and answers.