# Allow visitors to express their appreciation and make that statistic visible

Tags: feature-request, voting

**EDIT**
After careful reading, I have come to the conclusion that my request is not a duplicate of
[Public upvote counter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260956/public-upvote-counter), for the following reasons:

The accepted answer, which must also answer my request below, states:

> 1. You haven't given any reason as to how this would work, why you suggest it, or why this would be useful/beneficial.
> 2. And what happens to the vote from the user not logged in?
>    Does it get added to the current vote count, just like votes from users who are logged in?
> 3. Are you suggesting a new additional vote count for "votes by non-logged in users"?

**Why those valid objections do not apply here**

- Contrary to the older question, I have explained clearly my suggestion, how it would work (not its technicalities), why this feature would be useful, and to whom it would benefit.
- Nobody has answered saying the proposed feature is impractical, or impossible to carry out.
- The answers posted on the older question, and here, have failed to explain  why *this* feature request should be rejected.
- It has been pointed out  that votes from unregistered users are recorded, on the database.  But who actually sees these results? The user who asked the question? The users who responded? Not everyone who is a member of a SE site knows how to use SEDE.  We're not all computer analysts, developers, or programmers.
- It seems to me that many Stack Overflow users cannot see any benefit, unless they can personally gain some rep. **My feature request has NOTHING to do with earning rep; it is, instead, about transparency**.

The OP in the older question writes:

> This counter is to count is for public people so anyone who doesn't have SE account can upvote an answer he had a use of it.

**My idea is significantly different**,  every page would have one single button that says: "*Thanks! (I found this page useful/helpful)*". No one would earn rep, the answers upvoted and downvoted by the community would NOT be affected. The button is meant exclusively for visitors who do not want to open an account or who have not earned the 15 rep necessary to upvote. The total number of upvotes and downvotes per post would be unaffected.

In the end, the **[‘feedback’](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/556698)**  would no longer be anonymous or hidden in a crevice, but be visible to everyone on the Internet. **The data collected would be a powerful indication of the number of visitors who found a page useful.**

Quality, precision and utility should go hand in hand, why else are so many users dedicating their time in producing high quality content if it is not for the benefit of a wider public?

Please reopen this meta post.
Thank you.

---

**Request**

I'd like to propose a new feature among the discerning SO userbase.

Among community members, there is a strong tendency to keep an eye open for juicy "new" questions, and consequently, to post "new" answers. Understandably, many users tend to cast their votes on the newer material. But what happens to a question and its answers after only a month? After a year? Although the post and its answers remain helpful, and interesting, nothing more is heard about them. In addition, if we take into consideration that the number of votes cast decrease dramatically after three days, let alone 30, it's clear that good posts are penalised when their "hotness" has cooled down.

However, these contributions do enjoy a significant number of drive-by visitors. People who come to the Internet looking for explanations and answers. Therein lies the problem,  unless a casual visitor opens an account and earns 15 rep, they are not allowed to express their appreciation on an SE site.

### Proposal

An appreciation button, ENABLED for visitors and/or users with less than 5 rep, could be installed on the page saying: "Thanks, this page helped me" There would only be one button, it would be one button per page, while users with  15+ rep would still be expected to cast their votes on posts.

Over time, visitors and the authors of those older posts *would actually see* how helpful their contributions were on the Internet. There would be an additional but **widely available statistic for everyone to *see***.

---

**naysayers**

If this is a bad idea, it might well be for technical reasons,  could you please explain why?

1. @Patrick Hofman in his swift [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285782/223820), pointed out:

> If you compare the votes and views on this post, you know I could have more reputation if every visitor could vote.

I never once mentioned reputation. Is that what you think my proposal is about?

2. @Oded♦

> I am asking a serious question. One the post disappears from the front pages, why do you think a new button as you suggest would get more attention than the voting buttons?

If a newcomer, or a casual visitor has come across a page that has helped them, a visible button (or *counter*) would encourage a drive-by visitor to express their appreciation. Any downvotes cast by the community would naturally illustrate which posts were not helpful. It can be frustrating not to be able to say: "Hey, this *page* was really good!". Upvoting a post, as a visitor,  and not seeing any change seems a bit paradoxical (at least to me).

**Related**

[Offer a way for drive-by or new users to participate without leaving "I'm having this problem too" answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77725/offer-a-way-for-drive-by-or-new-users-to-participate-without-leaving-im-having)

Shadow Wizard's [**answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247419/223820) on *Who gets the “Was this post useful to you?” feedback?*

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there's already some data about this in each site. Just that we can't see the stats.

Comment: We do have such a button. It is the upvote button.

Comment: @Oded but you need 1. to open an account. 2. earn 15 points. Not everyone wants to open an account.

Comment: No, the upvote button is always there. If you click it, a record is stored in the database. It just doesn't earn you reputation.

Comment: @PatrickHofman but the record is INVISIBLE to everyone in the community. Who sees this record? Why not make it available to members?

Comment: [Anonymous feedback](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/556698)

Comment: @rene You'll probably infer, correctly, that I am basically a numbskull where writing queries is concerned. How does it work? Do I have to type each question separately, in order to view the results?

Comment: The bigger problem that SE has is NOT lack of appreciation, but too much appreciation. In other words, too many people are showing their appreciation without knowing whether a post is well-researched or useful/clear. They vote because they are Republicans or Democrats in some sites, and they vote just because the question reads interesting with fancy and eye-catching words.  SE doesn't need appreciation from complete strangers who don't know how it works. SE needs restriction to votes which are cast by low-rep users, especially those who have association bonus points.

Comment: @Rathony well that is a far better argument than "it's not true that information is stored, but invisible to the masses". If you post that as an answer, it's +1 from me, not because I agree, we *rarely* do, but because it is a concrete and reasonable objection, and explains why the SE team /developers might dislike this proposal.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not inferring anything, I'm trying to indicate that the button you're asking for is already there and the info gathered from that is stored. That leaves only the part of your question that asks for *make this statistic available* relevant. Running a  SEDE. query is inconvenient for the large group of users.

Comment: @rene the date is October 14th, the link you posted (Anonymous feedback)  only exists today. I have no idea what a SEDE query is, I'm sorry.

Comment: Sorry for being terse. What I meant to show with evidence that anonymous feedback is stored. That part of your FR is already covered. I don't expect that you nor many other users are willing or even thinking about visiting [The Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and run their own queries for their own posts. The part of your FR where you ask to make this statistics available does make sense. The part where you ask to add this anonymous feedback is I think [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: @rene that the anonymous feedback information is stored *but* it is invisible, and visitors do not see this stored information. My FR is about making that info *visible*. I bet one of the reasons why this information is not made widely available is because the number of anonymous upvotes is really low. Well, of course it is! Once a visitor upvotes an answer, and realises their vote hasn't made a dent, you quickly learn it's a waste of time.

Comment: I see users vent their frustrations in downvotes, whenever a good opportunity arises :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure if 8977016 anonymous down votes and 14598330 anonymous upvotes for only Stack Overflow can be considered really low. I guess that depends on your point of reference. But we'll see if this FR gains traction. The dialog that is shown to those users might not give a lasting impression

Comment: @rene I didn't know the results, I only guessed.

Comment: @rene  I just popped over to SO and discovered that 12,597,529 questions have been posted, so the 14,598,330 anonymous upvotes (for *both* questions and answers)  is not such an impressive a number as it appears at first glance. I'm no mathematician, but someone else could work out the average number of  anonymous upvotes  per post.

Comment: You might want to check when they introduced recording those statistics.

Comment: @PatrickHofman are you asking me? How am I supposed to know? EDIT; Where is SEDE?

Comment: OK, I've discovered that SEDE stands for Stack Exchange Data Explorer. That took me five minutes. Now I have found the login http://data.stackexchange.com/account/login @PatrickHofman so what do I do now?

Comment: What about this question makes it a counterpart to the hot question list?

Comment: @Servy A visitor button would act like a counterpart, maybe it's the wrong term, regardless the proposal has been met with fierce disapproval. .

Comment: @Mari-LouA How is letting <15 rep users vote on posts a "counterpart" to hot questions?

Comment: @Servy I am not speaking about upvotes or downvotes, there are NO votes, it's a button (or a counter) saying a PAGE (the whole page, not one answer. Not one question, the entire page) was helpful. It would be counterpart to the many upvotes on the HNQ which basically say they *LIKE* a post, or find it interesting.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes.  I'm aware that you're not talking about normal votes, but rather a separate vote count.  And as you've been told numerous times now, such a system already exists.  How is the existence of such a system a counterpart to hot network questions?

Comment: @Servy  OK, this storage of information, the anonymous votes, is for all intents and purposes hidden. If I look at any post that has 50 upvotes and see nothing else, I'm inclined to think it's a great post. But if there was also a counter, for visitors who don't want to go to the bother of setting up an account and earning 15 rep before expressing their appreciation, that said only 20 visitors thought the PAGE was helpful, I might reconsider.

Comment: @Servy (cont'd)  A page might have only 20 upvotes on an answer, and maybe only 10 upvotes on a question but if 20 visitors acknowledge they were helped, or that they found the page to be helpful that balances things out a little more. It's no longer a competition based on popularity; i.e. HNQ. Phew....

Comment: @Mari-LouA So you think that traditional votes cast by people with the reputation to have them shown is completely interchangeable with hot network questions?  Do you think that only posts on the hot network question list have regular votes?  If you want the votes of anonymous users to show up, feel free to propose something about it, but that has nothing to do with the hot network question list, nor is it a counterpart to it.  You could argue that it's a counterpart to traditional voting, sure, but that's orthogonal to hot network questions.

Comment: @Servy **So you think that traditional votes cast by people with the reputation to have them shown is completely interchangeable with hot network questions?** No, I do not. Where did I say that? But the HNQ does create a little jealousy and resentment among *some* users, does it not? Hey! If no one can see any merit in my idea, I accept it. I'm disappointed because I genuinely thought it was a nice idea. But fine. No one likes the FR. it's terrible. I get it. I disagree with the verdict, but I'm not going to argue.

Comment: `But the HNQ does create a little jealousy among users, does it not?` Maybe a bit, sure.  How is that in any way related to your proposal though?  If you would like to discuss this, then you'd probably want to propose something that would actually address this problem, (or explain how this proposal addresses that problem, because I'm not seeing it).

Comment: Because the button would say: `I found this page helpful` (or words to that effect), and currently visitors, unregistered users, users with 1 rep,  cannot say that. Is my English so poor that nobody understands?

Comment: @Mari-LouA That you want a seprate vote count is understandable.  Again, this is entirely unrelated to hot network questions.  You have explained nothing about how it is related to hot network questions.  Every time I've asked you how it's related, you've said that it is, and then went off and then provided some reasoning that in no way related to hot network questions and your idea.  Apparently there is nothing about your proposal that's related to hot network questions, so at least we know that now.

Comment: I'll make one last edit then, I'll delete the reference to the HNQ from the title. Will it make any difference. Not one iota.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125779/who-gets-the-was-this-post-useful-to-you-feedback http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/125779

Comment: @random OK, found the duplicate. Can't argue with that. I honestly did search before asking, I tried several different solutions.

Comment: @Rathony you were wrong not to post an answer, your comment earned you 5 upvotes. Next time, maybe. There is more than one difference between you and me, that's for sure. And if you took the time to read my comments, you might understand that I am talking about how to measure the usefulness of an answer or its question. I read somewhere that the traffic to SE is composed of 90% anonymous visitors, do we ignore them all?

Comment: Judging by the cool reception my proposal aroused, I am positive a written answer of yours would have been upvoted precisely by those who feel the same way as you do.

Comment: @Oded although this FR has been asked before, the answers posted on the duplicate does not answer my post. In fact, it was closed as duplicate of another question posted seven years previously. Could you change the duplicate question on my post please?

Comment: @Oded my FR is quite different from that of 7 years ago http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27618/getting-feedback-from-anonymous-users who says: `These "helpful" votes could be translated into upvotes for the user who provided the answer. Maybe for every 10(?) helpful votes, the user gets one upvote.` I never mentioned users earning rep.  And the button would be one, and one only per page.

Answer (score 1):

Statistics from 'upvotes' by users that don't have enough reputation are already stored, so the information you requested is already present. There is no need for an extra button too, it's all there.

I disagree with you that old posts aren't appreciated any more. I have some quite old posts, and some of them gain reputation every now and then (the usual token of appreciation present here). Indeed, users have to have enough reputation to vote, so that is the same for everyone. If you compare the votes and views on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21263515/993547), you'll see that I could earn more reputation if every visitor voted.

Why should SE have to show these statistics to the post owner? Well, I suppose it is nice to see how much you have missed out on. But besides that, there isn't much value in this metric to me personally.

In addition, why should we show this statistic to anonymous visitors? I don't see the added value of that. They see the vote counts from users in a community who know their site, and understand how the site work. Users know when a post is indeed 'good' and when it is not (for example, simply linking a very interesting blog post is not what we would consider a good answer).

I do think that it can be useful to some extent to show more information about posts. Maybe we can introduce a new privilege to see specific information on a post, like the site analytics privilege which already  exists. Maybe we could see the number of 'votes' cast by drive-by visitors, and if collected, their sources, and other useful/interesting data.

Comment: And where can I see this stored information? Please provide a link.

Comment: In the SE database. It is not made available to use (yet).

Comment: I didn't say old posts never gain rep, but the upvotes come in dribs and dabs.

Comment: "In all honesty, within the SE communities, the vast majority of "old" questions and answers become largely forgotten." So that isn't true if it gains reputation. If it doesn't, it wasn't useful to the active community after all.

Comment: *In the SE database. It is not made available to use (yet).* Right. I knew as much, so what's the point of storing such information? My proposal is that visitors are allowed to display their appreciation, and that statistic is made visible.

Comment: Upvotes come in dribs and drabs, you say, @Mari-LouA - what makes you think that people will react to this new button any different?

Comment: @Oded such resistance to a new idea, please try to be more open minded. Visitors cannot say "This helped me" or "Thanks for solving my problem" can they? Why is it that they sometimes edit questions, and answers anonymously? This happens fairly frequently, if SE installed a visitor button, these anonymous edits that are always rejected, rightly so, might well disappear in the future.

Comment: "Visitors cannot say...". Yes, they can. The can press the upvote button.

Comment: @Oded I meant that  the upvotes and downvotes come in dribs and drabs after the posts disappear from circulation, from the first pages. Why is my proposal meant with such aged cynicism?

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, they can't. Visitors have to first open an account and earn 15 rep. Look it up.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I am asking a serious question. One the post disappears from the front pages, why do you think a new button as you suggest would get more attention than the voting buttons?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - no, they don't. Anonymous users can click the upvote button and the downvote button. These are not recorded as upvotes/downvotes, but *are* recorded within the system.

Comment: @Oded I've edited my request to clarify.

Comment: And where did I say old posts are not appreciated anymore? Are you denying that the number of votes cast drop dramatically after three days? I said: `Although the post and its answers remain helpful, and interesting, nothing more is heard about them.`

Comment: I could show you dozens of highly upvoted answers and questions on EL&U that were upvoted because the users who posted were admired, highly respected, and generally provide good content. But it doesn't mean every answer or question posted by them glitters, and I include myself in that mix. And if we look at only the number of views generated by these highly upvoted questions, the numbers remain pretty stable. The questions that ask about basic stuff are the ones that attract the most views, like it or not.