# Add per question page site analytics

Tags: feature-request, site-analytics

Sometimes I get upvote surges, and I want to know which website referred to the question page in question.

Could be done by adding a page filter at: https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources , although I'd rather also have a date filter for referrals.

Comment: @random: thanks, the duplicate is absolutely correct. I'm glad at least one person understood my question. I've learnt my lesson: don't ever make any statement that could be interpreted as a taboo like "public upvotes". Or clarify that with a huge bold sentence.

Answer (score 6):

> Sometimes I get upvote surges, and I want to know who referred to the question page in question.

I don't think it is a good idea to be able see who opened the page or voted on it. For the first, privacy is the strongest argument, for the second, we have gone over that a million times: votes are anonymous.

> I suspect this would also be useful for some voting fraud investigations / other moderation investigations.

But that is not to you, but to moderators. There are cases where automatically flags are raised. Then moderators and employees can investigate the suspected voting fraud. This is covered in the tools for moderators already. They get the information they need, or else employees can gather that information. There is no need to give that information to other users.

Comment: What I meant to say is which website referred to the question

Comment: How would that be useful when investigating voting fraude?

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 Also see the last part of [this post of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285782/245360) which describes some post statistics page.

Comment: Voting fraud: maybe there is a group who is up voting me because of a post. But maybe not useful. Not my main motivation. 