# What happens with votes cast with rep < 15 exactly?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, post-feedback

On many stackexchange sites I haven't enough reputation to cast an up-vote. Always I get the message *"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"*.

What does **recorded** mean exactly?

- Can the owner of the up-voted question/answer see in any kind, that he/she got my up-vote?
- Does he/she get rep for this?
- What happens with these votes, if I reach the 15 rep? Will they take effect subsequently?
- Or are they just recorded for my "vote-history"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does recorded mean exactly?

Recorded in database, separate table. (Not along with ordinary votes)
It can be queried via SEDE, as explained [in this other answer I wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247419/152859).

> Can the owner of the up-voted question/answer see in any kind, that he/she got my up-vote?

No, this is not possible.

> Does he/she get rep for this?

No, no reputation is gained to any side.

> What happens with these votes, if I reach the 15 rep? Will they take effect subsequently?

As explained in the answers to [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285181/once-i-reach-15-reputation-will-my-old-votes-be-taken-into-account), nothing happens to those votes, and they don't have subsequent effect, you'll have to vote again.

> Or are they just recorded for my "vote-history"?

No, they are not part of the votes tab in the profile.

Comment: Thanks, that covers everything! So up-voting without min 15 rep is a waste of time?

Comment: @Artery no, that's not waste of time. The data is stored, Stack Exchange might still do something with it one day, e.g. give badges to authors of posts who got lots of those feedbacks.

Comment: Okay, but for the near future there are no concrete plans for it?
Then I'll keep up-voting :D