# How do you revoke not-a-real-vote post feedback?

Tags: support, voting, post-feedback, undo

When a user without enough rep to cast a certain vote (upvote or downvote) attempts to do so, they instead register anonymous, [tracked post feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288051/336163). They get a message like:

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15/125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

If I click again on the vote button after having cast such not-a-real-vote feedback, *I simply get the same message again*, as opposed to the behavior when casting a *real vote*, where clicking the button again *revokes* the vote so long as it is done within the voting grace period.

If I have enough reputation to cast a vote, I can withdraw such vote as long as I do so within the grace period. If I don't have enough rep to cast a "real" vote, how do I revoke my pseudo-vote post feedback?

I'm not asking about *why* users below certain rep levels can't vote, nor how to view non-vote post feedback, nor whether such feedback [automatically converts to a real vote once one's rep increases (it doesn't)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285181/336163). I'm asking about how one can handle "accidentally" casting post feedback that one did not intend to do, or where one has immediate second thoughts as to whether or not such post feedback was warranted.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't.  Think of those non-votes more like link clicks that go into a big pool of data, not individual, tracked events.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There is no mechanism built for redacting it, and it's unlikely we would build such a thing given the numbers don't actually affect anything.

Comment: This answer answers the *how* on redacting, but not *why not*, so is not particularly helpful when saying it is unlikely to be built in.  If the numbers don't actually affect anything, why is it that *"Votes cast by those with less than 15/125 reputation are recorded"*?

Comment: @ChrisRogers this answers the question asked in the title. If there is more than one question, it should be closed anyway and be separated into two different questions. So nothing wrong with the answer, rather perhaps with the question.

Comment: The reason seems implicit to me: "the numbers don't actually affect anything [so it would be nonzero work for zero benefit]".