# Could the < 15 rep voting information text be made clearer

Tags: discussion, voting, privileges

On the post "[Feature Test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction?cb=1)" an edit was made to include the text

> "..."  (unlike voting, which is only available for users with 15 reputation or more).

Which made me a bit confused, as I remembered the tooltip for voting when you don't have 15 reputation yet to say something along the lines of "the vote is recorded, but not displayed". Due to me remembering that I went into the MSO chatroom, asking if this edit could be deleted. Since to my knowledge this was inaccurate information.

Some kind users in there pointed out that the information is in fact correct, and that the votes are in fact not used for anything besides site metrics, as explained in [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288051/what-happens-with-votes-cast-with-rep-15-exactly) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285181/once-i-reach-15-reputation-will-my-old-votes-be-taken-into-account). Not even when the user does reach the threshold.

Now the exact message when a < 15 rep users tries to vote is: (emphasis mine)

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation **are recorded**, but do not change the **publicly** displayed post score.

[image: screenshot of the < 15 rep vote popup]

to me this message (clearly) indicates that the vote is in fact cast (".. are recorded .."), but *just* not being displayed publicly. (".. do not change the publicly displayed ..")

Now my questions is, is it just me, and am I reading the meaning behind it incorrectly (Not a native English speaker), or is the text actually a bit vague?

Besides the 2 Meta questions linked earlier I was not able to find anything in the help pages/faq about what happens to a users vote that has < 15 reputation (like the vote also not being converted once the user reaches 15 rep), maybe a page containing this information could be added, and linked in the message?

Alternatively, maybe change the text to be the same text someone gets when they are not logged in at all "You need 15 reputation to upvote posts.". As this seems to capture what's actually happening way better.
[image: Screenshot of not logged in vote popup]

---

(In spirits of the [poetry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349555/a-yaakov-ellis-inspired-meta-se-poetry-contest-write-poems-win-rep), an attempt at haiku)

> Edit I saw done
> Left in state of confusion
> To meta I turned

Comment: This has already been requested: [Change the message shown to registered users without enough reputation to vote to something less confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330254/change-the-message-shown-to-registered-users-without-enough-reputation-to-vote-t)