# What does "your feedback has been recorded" mean when casting a vote was declined because of low rep?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, new-users, error-message

As I was trying to cast a vote with an SE account with <15 rep, I read:

> Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 [reputation](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

[image]

What does "your feedback has been recorded" mean when casting a vote was declined because of low rep? Does that mean the vote will be displayed only once that account reaches >= 15rep?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback, under "Anonymous feedback".

Comment: @Ollie thx, even if the account is registered?

Comment: I don't know about that, but, AFAIK, the vote won't be displayed when you top 15.  You'll have to upvote it again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Once I reach 15 reputation, will my old votes be taken into account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285181/once-i-reach-15-reputation-will-my-old-votes-be-taken-into-account) (A more [direct duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288051/) is here, but it's closed as a dupe of the former)

Comment: @Ollie interesting, then I wonder what "your feedback has been recorded" does, and whether it is useful at all :)

Comment: In addition to the duplicate target, there are also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247419/798831, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288051/what-happens-with-votes-cast-with-rep-15-exactly, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125779/who-gets-the-was-this-post-useful-to-you-feedback/247419#247419, etc etc, which are a few too many to write another answer, I think ;)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Actually, if you read the link description, it says "anonymous and low rep post feedback", so I'm pretty sure that includes unregistered accounts.

Comment: @Ollie thanks, many dupes indeed, I'd suggest revising the message https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366464/178179 then.