# Anonymous feedback is a moving target

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, post-feedback

Yi Jiang [inquired in chat earlier](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/707026#707026) whether anyone noticed the content shifting when hovering over the anonymous feedback section, and in Firefox and IE, [indeed it does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing/99408#99408):

[image: offset before and during hover]

2 pixels isn't a huge jump, but it's still noticeable, and the fix is easy enough. Just remove the default 5 pixel top and bottom margin on inputs from those buttons:

```
input.anon-vote {
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting should be fixed in the next drop!