# "Was this post useful to you?" moved to be above the comments?

Tags: discussion, post-feedback

I tend to use the "Was this post useful to you?" option of giving feedback a lot when I'm on a computer I don't normally use. I think its a great way to give feedback in such a case where logging in on a different computer would just be too much effort than I want to make at the time (so sue me, I'm a user - we tend to be lazy).

What my issue is that the "Was this post useful to you?" message pops up below all the comments. If an answer has 5 comments showing (especially if they're longer comments) I may not even see the "Was this post useful to you?" message on the screen. It just seems out of place and I always forget that its all the way down there.

The comments are good, but if I'm too lazy to log in, I'm too lazy to read through the comments, and may not make it all the way to the bottom before realizing I can answer the "Was this post useful to you?" message.

Perhaps moving it to the top of the comments, but below the post would be more ideal. What does everyone else think?

Comment: Related: [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing/98669#98669) (Jeff's comment suggests he wasn't too keen on moving it at the time)

Comment: Maybe they don't want to collect data from lazy people...

Comment: @TimStone Thanks for the link, I didn't see a post with a similar title so assumed it hadn't been brought up before.

Comment: @WesleyMurch The whole concept of getting this feedback is geared to getting signal from the **90%** of lazy people who visit the site and don't register (or are simply not logged in). Obviously, they want this feedback.