# Give Moderators/10k users a way to view the anonymous feedback data for a specific question

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, anonymous, post-feedback

[Anonymous user feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98630/133693) was added quite some time back. In addition to this, 10k users can look at [the summarized data](/tools/post-feedback) as well as the feedback categorized as underrated, overrated and so on.

[image: Anon Feedback]

However, there's no way to search through this data, neither is there a way to pull data on a particular question.

I believe the ability to pull up anonymous feedback on specific questions would be highly useful - especially on (old) posts which have very high views.

An option to pull up this data would be by means of adding an option to the Mod menu available under every post.

---

Since the post feedback option is also visible to 10k users, it would make sense if the ability to pull up specific question post feedback was also available to 10k users.

Comment: maybe this is a 20k feature? or higher?

Comment: Most sites only have a couple of 20k users, so that would limit its usefulness on anything but the trilogy

Comment: The tricky thing is that most posts have 0 feedback, if you constantly need to drill down its a problem. perhaps we need a way to display it on the question / answer if it is there

Answer (score 4):

This can be considered [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), for real this time.

10k+ rep users and moderators can view the anonymous feedback the same way anyone else (including anonymous users!) can: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/525670).

This query, for example, shows the feedback on the [highest voted question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809):

```sql
Select count(VoteTypeId) as 'total votes',
  SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'number of up votes',
  SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'number of down votes'
From PostFeedback
where postid=11227809
```

You can see all the anonymous votes per post like this (my query excludes deleted posts):

```sql
Select postid as [Post Link], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'number of up votes',
  SUM(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'number of down votes'
From PostFeedback
where exists(
    select id from posts 
    where posts.id=postfeedback.postid
)
group by postid
```

Note that trying to get all the voting data at once from large sites like Stack Overflow is destined for failure. You're limited to 50k rows of results, and you'll probably time out if you try to get the post links. You'll need to get the data in chunks, or limit the query in another way.

But you still have a lot of freedom, since there's a lot more than just anonymous feedback to query from.

Answer (score -6):

According to the answers at [Who gets the "Was this post useful to you?" feedback?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125779/who-gets-the-feedback-when-someone-click-yes-or-no-on-was-this-post-usefull-to), this request is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: actually, no. I've seen those pages, they show which question has got highest/lowest feedback. I can't pull up feedback on each post on demand, neither can I search them

Comment: Yeah, but things have been marked completed for less.