# Anonymous user feedback about my posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, anonymous, post-feedback

I think a feature that allows me to view the *Was this post useful to you?* [anonymous user feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing) about my posts can be a really helpful tool.

It will allow me to know where people think I'm wrong, what kind of answers people like to read and what kind of answers people dislike, etc.

I think it can be so helpful that it should have a low reputation limit to gain the privilege.

Comment: What about the yes/no of anonymous (drive-by?) users is more useful than the votes of registered/regular users?

Comment: Though not quite the same for various reasons, there *is* [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits?userId=601179).

Comment: related [Give Moderators/10k users a way to view the anonymous feedback data for a specific question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116715)

Answer (score 5):

Until this is implemented proper, you could use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for this. Anonymous feedback is public information, but currently only in the data dumps.

There's already a useful query that shows anonymous feedback on all your posts, sorted by number of helpful votes: [**Feedback on my posts**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts).

Comment: That query is indeed nice. Reveals surprising facts about what worked for large, google-wielding masses and what didn't (often quite a difference to the actual votes of a post).