# Anonymous Feedback disappeared from the Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, data-explorer, post-feedback

I went to use [my query for "Anonymous Feedback for a specific question"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers), but now it throws an error:

> Invalid object name 'PostFeedback'.

It seems the `PostFeedback` table is not in the current SEDE snapshot!
This also busts [Waffles' (DBA "sam.saffron") query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts) and invalidates [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130097/148310).

I verified that *Anonymous Feedback* data has not been moved to some other tables (Posts, PostHistory, or Votes).

**Can we please get `PostFeedback` put back in the Data Explorer?**  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My fault!

I missed this in the re-write of the import.  I also didn't see this post until I was alerted to it.  The magical `Union 'PostFeedback'` has been added and the data import job has just been kicked off.  Everything except Stack Overflow will be updated in the next 30 min and SO will take about another 2 hours after that...you'll see the dates on the front page update as the job rolls through site-by-site.