# Where can I see anonymous feedback stats? Update the privilege pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, privileges, 10k-tools, post-feedback

Yesterday I reached the 10k points milestone. That means that *I have access to moderator tools* according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

In that page I read this:

> This privilege also grants you access to the following lists:
>
> - ...
> - Anonymous feedback stats
> - ...

Where can I find the anonymous feedback stats?

I looked on [these pages](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Stats&daterange=today) but I didn't find them... I know [that they are public](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts) but I expected some tools to see them.

---

Seems that [this feature was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209655/post-feedback-link-is-broken/209787#209787) (thanks [@Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213734/where-can-i-see-anonymous-feedback-stats#comment688319_213734)). I recommend to update the [privilege pages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) with up-to-date information.

Comment: It was removed not long ago due to becoming too "heavy". Going to find it...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209787/152859

Comment: You can turn this post into feature request asking to update the privilege page, I did my best to update ordinary posts like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116715/152859). :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think that [the privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) pages must be updated. They are a little bit out of date (e.g. the screen shots).

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: What's wrong with the screenshots on that page? I don't see anything really weird.

Comment: @Mat For example I can't see the **`Close question`** button that is in the [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y9KPp.png). *Vote to close or delete. Use this option if you agree the post should be closed or deleted. The button will show the amount of votes already cast against the post, if applicable.* This is also outdated, I guess. [**Edit tags**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M36io.png) was removed, I think.

Comment: The close question button is there, on questions only. Delete thingy also there, but subject to additional restrictions on delete votes I guess. Edit tags is there too (10k only, check on SO not here).

Comment: @Mat The `Edit tags` button [doesn't exist](http://i.imgur.com/lUgIj64.png). `Close button` also [is not there](http://i.imgur.com/GF0IwjW.png). Yes, it exists in the questions, but not in the [review flags page](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged).

Comment: @イオニカビザウ: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DFwOr.png - they all exist. The retag thing isn't an ordinary button though, only appears on hover.

Comment: @Mat Yes, `Edit tags` appears on hover, but I can't see **Delete answer** and **Close question** buttons in flag review page. Is this a bug?

Comment: Delete has quite a few restrictions even at 20k, there might not be eligible posts in the queue for you right now. There are much fewer questions in the flag queue than answers (a lot of question flags send posts to the review queues rather than the flag queue), make sure you search a bit.

Comment: Yes, please update the privileges page.