# Add "Anonymous feedback stats" back to the description of the 10k privilege

Tags: feature-request, privileges, 10k-tools, help-center

I just saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213734/323179) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) request which I think should be reverted.

As you may be able to see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback), those with 10k+ can access the "Post Feedback" tool. However, the [privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) doesn't mention this. This is because the tools were broken for about [5 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322162/323179), only being fixed fairly recently. For reference, [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130804072423/https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) is what the page looked like when it used to mention this tool.

Comment: The team generally doesn't remove the [tag:status-completed] tag from implemented requests once it gets applied. That said, this counter-request is definitely valid.