# Feature request: Expose stream of ignored downvotes

Tags: feature-request, voting, feedback

When you lack reputation to cast a proper downvote on a site, there is a box explaining that it was registered somehow anyway, but doesn't really explain in much detail what this really means.

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

[What happens with votes cast with rep < 15 exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288051/what-happens-with-votes-cast-with-rep-15-exactly) explains that this feedback will be visible via SEDE, but this is arguably not a very useful place for putting these to actual use - the database is only updated and republished periodically ([When will data.SE get updated data?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data) says weekly but having a stable, recent, authoritative source would be nice - any better pointers?)

For monitoring tools like the ones running in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) chat rooms, it would be useful to get access to this feedback in something approaching real time. Could these be made available e.g. as an RSS feed or on a web socket?

(I guess upvotes should be included as well, though it's less clear how exactly those could be put to immediate use.)

Comment: Anonymous feedback is shown in the 10k tools.

Comment: But then a bot would need to have 10k on all the sites it monitors. But thanks for the pointer - I earned this privilege 88k ago on Stack Overflow and never discovered it.

Comment: Well, it's new-ish. It used to be there years ago but was removed because the query was expensive to run. Taryn fixed that and we added it back a few months ago.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate (from 2012!): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116715/give-moderators-10k-users-a-way-to-view-the-anonymous-feedback-data-for-a-specif

Comment: More background for the 10k privilege: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328213/add-anonymous-feedback-stats-back-to-the-description-of-the-10k-privilege