# Make the number of follows for a post available to the post creator

Tags: feature-request, follow-post

When I asked whether there's a way of knowing how many members are following one's post, I was told this:

> For the most part, you can't. Follows have never been publicly available.
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386397/1322117

However, *how many* follows a post have isn't the same as *who* the followers are. Sharing the *total number* of follows for a post doesn't at all necessitate making *any individual* follows publicly available.

I hold that making the *total number* of follows for a post available to the *post creator* (and to no one else) would be a really valuable aid, without which it's impossible to know for sure if editing a post makes it more or less interesting to the community. Neither views nor saves (which are also private) are as good indicators as follows.

Therefore I move that Stack Exchange make available the *total number* of follows for a post available to the *post creator*, while still keeping individual follows private (anonymous).

Comment: Knowing the number of follows doesn't tell you anything about the interesting-ness effect of an edit either, only the change in follows over time would, and only if there was a statistically meaningful change. A static value gives neither of these, and hiding the numbers from everybody else means there is no way to compare the effect either.

Comment: If you make an edit and then you get 10 new follows on the post, how do you know it's _due to the edit_ and not some other contributing factor (like a comment on another post, or in chat, or someone tweeting the question, or coincidence)? Also, people can follow a post for a wide variety of reasons, so you can't assume that just because you got a bump in follows after a bump in increased visibility due to the edit, it doesn't mean the edit was directly successful (e.g. it was a good edit that made more people interested in answering your question). Getting an answer is a much better indicator.

Comment: You already have votes. If you edit a post and that makes it good you should attract upvotes, if the post was bad before and bad after your edit you'll likely still get downvotes.