# Do the "Was this post useful to you?" Yes/No linkbuttons on comment posts mean anything to a stackoverflow user?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)

Do the "Was this post useful to you?" Yes/No link buttons on comment posts mean anything to a Stack Overflow user?  I have been clicking them occasionally, then later checking my username history, but it doesn't seem they are recorded for reading to userspace, which I think would be useful itself.

Comment: Relevant: [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)

Comment: OK, terrific, thank you so much. The feature request direction I had was to make the feature more useful for people who bother to log in, specifically: keep a link list of the "yes, useful" clicks so the user can later review what was useful for study purposes.  Incidentally, I would probably only go so far as tallying a user's count of "no, un-useful" clicks because it seems it might encourage topic-trolling.

Comment: @stackuser83 - there's a "favourites" function that's more designed for keeping track of useful things you discover.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  It would still be nice to have a link list of "yes, useful" comments, especially if it could help preserve them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They tend to get translated into votes of one kind or another but there's no hard and fast rules. There is a [tool for high rep users](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/overrated) (>10K) can use that has a mode for viewing questions where there is a disparity between the post score and the anonymous feedback.

I look through there from time to time (not particularly often) and usually act on a fair number of the posts, even if not all of them. I assume others do this too, so even if it's not directly visible it does contribute and direct attention to unsung or overrated posts.

Comment: That's interesting, I've never heard of that section of the 10k tools.  +1.

Comment: On the other hand, @jad, even [a 43k+ views post](http://superuser.com/questions/395719/how-do-i-uninstall-windows-8-consumer-preview) might only have [21 feedback votes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oH8c8.png). But: on Super User there's about 1 feedback vote for each 5 regular votes.

Comment: Oh, actually the recent figures are even close to 1 feedback vote for each 2 regular votes. Nice.