# What happens when a user clicks 'Was this post useful to you?'

Tags: discussion, unregistered-users, anonymous, posts, post-feedback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)

Whenever we move the mouse cursor to the 'add comment' area, a display appears asking 'Was this post useful to you?'.

When we provide feedback as 'yes' or 'no', what happens then, do the asker of question gets points or its just a formality.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/

Comment: This post explains that, its an idea to get feedback from anonymous users, but it doesnt explain, whats the effect when user clicks 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj *"This click data is currently being evaluated to see what we can do with it. Ideas welcome!"* It doesn't result in any reputation changes that I'm aware of. It's just being gathered and (unless there has been an update since) it's still up for grabs to see if anything useful can be done with the data.

Comment: Where these points are gathered. do the community gathers these points. If it doesnt affect anything to click yes or no, then why the community is gathering anonymous users feedback.

Comment: Did you even read the information contained within that link? It's SO/SE who gather that information and the goal is *"to offer the 90% of our traffic that is anonymous users a way to provide more meaningful feedback on posts rather than passively incrementing a view counter."* Read that question and all of its answers and comments. It contains a wealth of information and ideas.