# How much reputation do I get for positive feedback?

Tags: support, post-feedback

I have been using Stack Overflow for a month now. There are "yes" and "no" options for positive and negative response, respectively. I was wondering, how does this feedback affect my reputation?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98630/187824

Comment: @hims056, thanks. really helpful post. my question may have been a duplicate, but I couldn't find it in the auto completion/suggestion when I was asking it. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't get any reputation off of those whatsoever. These feedback options are only gathered for statistical purposes as far as I know. And as of yet I don't think that there are any set plans for what to do with the data gathered (or at least I'm unaware of any).

What you could use it for however is to gather some insights into how useful you have been yourself to unregistered users of the site via [this data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80997/feedback-on-my-posts). It might help you in improving your own contributions and gathering more upvotes in the process.

Comment: I have never been notified about the `feedback` to my answers/questions. Does this mean - nobody clicked `yes`. I mean Do I get notified when somebody clicks `yes` or `no`. It may help me improve  knowing the usefulness of the post.

Comment: No, you do not get notified at all. You can occasionally use the data explorer query I've linked to, to see if anything happened. Having just checked it for you, it seems that at the moment you've received no feedback on your contributions.

Comment: Oh! sorry. Forgot to click on that. Thanks.