# Up vote not counted when you are not logged in

Tags: bug, status-deferred, post-feedback

This is a weird one, and I hope I have the repro steps right.

(using IE10)

1. make sure you are logged out
2. up vote a question (note the count before you vote - mine was 27)
3. you will be asked to login, do that (I use Google with 2 step if that matters)
4. you will be sent back to the question page, and it will look like you have upvoted the answer, but the count is the same (27)
5. remove you vote, the count goes down. (26)

That is the bug. The rest are some steps I did to validate I wasn't confused on the vote count

1. refreshed the page, voted up again  (count was 27)
2. loaded a new browser in private mode, went to the question while not logged in and noted count (27)
3. in the original window I removed the downvote (count was 26)
4. refreshed the other window count was still 27)

Here is an image of the two windows on the same post with different counts.  I guess it is possible that someone downvoted/remove a vote at the some moment I voted up, but that sounds unlikely.

[image]

Comment: That's not voting but rather anonymous post feedback. Visitors who aren't logged in can click "this post was useful" link below every post, and upvote arrow has same effect. Still a bug though, the downvote should be disabled for anonymous  visitors.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If you provide anonymous feedback and then sign in shortly after, the anonymous feedback you left should be automatically converted to a vote. I'm not sure if this is actually a counting bug or just a display bug, though... I've had some issues getting this feature to work on my end.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood. After voting I was asked to log in, and I did. the vote looks like it counted, but I don't think it really did. How is that anonymous feedback?

Comment: @Anna thanks, wasn't aware of that. Is it documented somewhere? Went through the posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98630/152859) and such thing wasn't mentioned.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm not sure if it is. I think it was added as a "nice to have".

Comment: @Anna that's pretty major change. Joe, anonymous feedback is something different than voting as explained in the post linked in my comment to Anna above.

Comment: You can roughly think of anonymous feedback as voting for people who aren't logged in that's not visible to anyone except users with "diamond moderator" access to the site.

Comment: @AnnaLear Don't 10k's have access to that info, too? Or is it just a subset? [Via this; a 10k tool](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback) Or... am I thinking of something different?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Oh yeah, that's the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried reproducing this several times, and I think I have a handle on what happened.

So yes, when I was asked to log in after voting it looked like my vote was counted (the up arrow changed color), but the count didn't change. I think was happened was...I had previously up voted the answer (doh!)

So why would it let me remove the vote? Well, looking at the rev history across my voting history, the answer had been edited so I was allowed to remove it.

I am pretty sure that is what happened. Although I don't know why the "in-private" session of IE was showing a different count. Perhaps something was just being cached?  I'll just assume gremlins or something. Anyway, I am pretty sure I think everything just happened to align in a confusing way, and I didn't notice it. Thanks for the quick responses on this though!

Comment: Neat, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Upvotes and downvotes by anonymous users (who then log in) are not counted at all on **meta** sites (except Meta Stack Overflow). There's no specific reason for this, other than that it's technically more complicated and we haven't gotten to it yet.

The only part of this bug report I'm confused by is "and it will look like you have upvoted the answer". Are you sure it looked upvoted? I would have expected it to look the same.

Comment: So votes are supposed to be further associated with a user who, after the fact, logs in proper? If not, how could a vote be _removed_? Anna seems to note this more clearly, and expectedly.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I'm not sure I'm following you, and perhaps I wasn't clear myself. On non-meta sites, if you upvote anonymously and then log in, the end result is as if you had logged in and then upvoted.

Comment: ...or perhaps I had too much whisky; forgive, and just forget, me. Maybe the _meta_ part threw me off? I don't even see the name of a site in the OP, let alone a meta reference.

Comment: Ah, I determined that it was on meta.photo.stackexchange.com based on the provided screenshot.

Comment: yes, i am sure it looked upvoted (the arrow had changed) I think I know what happened though. see my answer

Comment: @Emmett I just viewed some posts as anonymous visitor and couldn't see any "feedback" link anymore. Did the upvote option replaced it? If so, [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98630/152859) should be updated.