# Sudden disappearance of four votes on a question

Tags: support, voting, specific-question

I am troubled by the sudden disappearance of votes on [this Question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8985/where-do-russian-historians-have-linked-the-legitimacy-of-the-new-russian-state). I distinctly remember there being two upvotes (one of them being mine) and three downvotes. Then suddenly there was only one downvote but no upvotes. While the net vote total did not change, it still bothers me that this happened.

What might explain this disappearance?

Comment: I don't understand. The question is at -5. 2 recorded downvotes yesterday, three today.

Comment: @Mat Yes in the meantime, four additional downvotes were apparently added, bringing the current total to zero upvotes five downvotes. However, there was an earlier vote status where the total was two upvotes and three downvotes. Then suddenly zero up, one down. I am certain that I had not taken back my upvote.

Comment: http://history.stackexchange.com/posts/8985/timeline

Comment: @EugeneSeidel I think I remember at least one upvote as well (probably yours, cause I also remember your +1 comment).

Comment: Maybe people retracted their votes?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Don't know who the other voters were and cannot speak for them. I do know that I did not retract my upvote.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thank you, am not used to reading a "timeline". In the very first grey-background line, does it list three upvotes? Are they for the question or for the answer?

Comment: @Eugene: the second line details the first. It's -3 for the Q, +3 for the A.

Comment: How do you know upvotes disappeared? You don't have enough reputation to see the number of up/downvotes. You can only see the current total.

Comment: Thanks @Mat... so I'm not sure the timeline is helpful. It does not show any of the deleted comments, hence I suspect that it won't show deleted votes, either.

Comment: @Mischa I installed a [script from userscript.org](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/125051) that gives low-rep users the ability to see # down / up votes.

Comment: One thing that might explain the disappearing votes is the vote fraud script. The OP of the question in question has posted a few questions in quick succession, and the script _might_ have identified some of the votes as invalid (because they were too close to each other). However that would also mean that votes disappear from the other questions as well.

Comment: @Yannis: that would be visible in the OP's rep history I think

Comment: @Mat Hm, yes, it probably would.

Comment: That script is not 100% correct and fails a lot.

Comment: Definitely not the vote-fraud script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no record of any up-votes to that particular question, ever. You can certainly up-vote it *now* if you're so inclined.

You can view your recent votes here: https://history.stackexchange.com/users/825/eugene-seidel?tab=votes

FWIW, someone *did* up-vote that question anonymously about three hours ago; [these "votes" are recorded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing), but not shown as ordinary votes on the post. However, the IP address this vote came from isn't one that you've used (at least, not one that shows up in our logs associated with your account) - it's possible you visited it from an unusual location and voted without realizing you weren't logged in, but I can't prove that.

Comment: O.K. thanks. So if you've done an audit and found nothing... hmmm...

Comment: Well apparently this is turning into a big embarrassment for me... from that voting history page, I find a link to http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8977/homo-sapiens-sapiens-are-genetic-studies-to-be-trusted and there is my "+1 Interesting" comment that I had thought gone and my upvote. Sheesh... can this question be buried under a big rock please?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Well, if that's what actually happened, we share the embarrassment. I was absolutely certain I saw at least one upvote in the first question.