# Mark answers for upvote

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, up-votes

Would it make sense to allow users with reputation lower than 15 to *mark an answer* for upvote? The upvote would not be executed directly but would be delayed until the user actually reaches the minimum reputation. During this period the upvote button would show in a color other than orange for the new user.

**Assumption:** Many users "get to know" StackOverflow by searching for answers on the internet. They find useful answers which they can rate well because the rating would immediately follow their visit to StackOverflow. This may happen many times before they take the next step to ask questions or answer questions themselves. Also, this may happen over a rather extended time period.

**Problem:** The requirement to have a reputation of 15 is a relatively high "hurdle" for upvoting compared to just having an account with default reputation one. When sporadic users reach the minimum reputation they will

- most likely not remember which answers they had found up over time and/or
- they may not feel like trying to work through their SO history to upvote the answers.

**Solution:** Lowering the hurdle but at the same delaying the upvoting would

- give a much better overview/representation of how useful answers are for the WHOLE internet community and
- would still impose a minimum quality gate against abuse.

Comment: A: 15 rep is one accepted answer, 3 upvotes on a question, or 2 upvotes on an answer. Not even counting edits. B: It just adds another confusing aspect. Try telling users, "Oh, you can upvote that answer. But sorry, *your* upvote will not take effect until you get 15 rep. Oh, and you still can't upvote questions."

Comment: Well, there is the [anonymous feedback](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing) options that are presented to people without accounts. I know this feedback is being examined, so it is being tracked, but I don't know if it's providing useful information.

Answer (score 12):

This would involve maintaining a table in the Stack Exchange database to keep track of a potentially countless number of these "pending upvotes".  This may even create problems in terms of available bandwidth and performance of the engine.  90% of a healthy Stack Exchange site's traffic comes from search engines; therefore, assuming a majority of Stack Overflow's visits come from visitors who don't yet have accounts, this could potentially be a lot of data stored that may never actually get converted to real up votes.  That's a lot of data for very little benefit, as well as a lot of extra bandwidth, compute cycles, and database writes for very little benefit.

Additionally, one of the things that eventually cause a visitor to convert to a community member is the promise of permissions. I was a visitor for years, until I saw an unjustly-downvoted answer that helped me solve a tough problem. So I earned the 15 points necessary to upvote the answer as a reward to that person for helping.

There's lots of stuff that helped me prior to that date; I can't remember any of it, and quite frankly, none of that really matters, as I wasn't trusted by the community at that time to properly rate the answers based on the voting guidelines. Thus, decisions I would have made before I was trusted don't necessarily become true or trusted simply because I'm trusted today. As an almost 15k user on Stack Overflow, I know a lot more than I did as a 1 rep user, and that includes knowing what voting is all about, what it means to upvote something, and what a good answer looks like. To count all of the times I hit the upvote button when I wasn't yet a user would be a disservice to the reputation system, since I didn't know what I was doing then.

Aside from that, many visitors likely won't understand or care what the delayed upvote means. If they cared, they would have created an account long ago and contributed enough to earn the 15 points it takes to participate in the voting process. Such a feature would really only benefit people who are concerned about reputation, those answering questions by 1 rep users who long for an extra 10 points for their efforts. Just focus on writing good quality answers, and reputation will come. :)

Comment: (: I remmember the feeling: *"Wow, great stuff, how do I get those points to upvote it?!"*

Answer (score 4):

Getting 15 rep isn't that hard, you need just a few up votes, a few accepted edits, or 1 accepted answer. This was intentional so that you only need minimal contributions to be able to up-vote. There's no reason to mark something as to favorite, since you already have ways to do this. One of those ways is to simply favorite the question, or you could just make a bookmark and save it in a folder called "To up vote when I have enough rep"

Answer (score 4):

1. 15 is a ridiculously ***LOW*** hurdle. Do you know how many 4+ digit rep users I come across daily that have no idea how to use the site? It's appalling.
2. What is the point of requiring minimum reputation to gain some privilege, if we're going to allow them to make the decisions before they've earned the rep to do so? The reason they need to wait is not so that some recipient can't get rep from their upvote, it's to ensure that the person has enough experience with the site to be able to make those decisions wisely. If we let them make the decision before they've earned any rep at all, and are just going to turn on all those up-votes the instant they hit 15 rep, why not just apply them immediately?
3. If a user really wants to upvote a question, they already have the ability to mark a post for a future up-vote: they can favorite the question or create a bookmark pointing to the URL that pops up when you click "share" under an answer.

Comment: yes, agreed, correct.