# Why can't I upvote something if it just helped me

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

It seems it would be very nice if a user could comment on or upvote something that just helped them solve a problem.  I was disappointed that I couldn't enforce an answer or comment that really helped me because my reputation is so low.  Seems silly, because some of the upvotes would probably be a lot greater if people doing searches could upvote them.

Comment: Probably spam... Anyway, here's a tick! +1

Comment: It prevents creating fake accounts to give free votes to yourself. you just need 15 to do that anyway, it's not much.

Comment: I think the reputation boundary has to be reached to attain some privileges. You can't just come in as a first time user and uptick, it's simple. P.S Uptick +1 from me , now you have the privilege.

Comment: Actually you can uptick, it send something called "post feedback" which is documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98630/152859). While it doesn't affect reputation, it does get collected and maybe at some point it will have some effect. :)

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn congrats for round 2000!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks :D

Answer (score -3):

You can vote and comment once you have sufficient reputation. New users and those with low reputation cannot.

Here is what you can do as your reputation increases: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges.

Comment: The OP seems to be aware of that, he's asking for the reasoning behind it.